# How to catch error creating database table in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, error-handling

In my Wordpress Plugin, I create a new database table on activation like this :

```
function create_table_db( array $table ){
    $upgrade_file_path = ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php";
    if( !@require_once( $upgrade_file_path ) ){
        require_once( $upgrade_file_path );
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    ...
    $query = "CREATE table...";
    ...
    return \dbDelta( $query );

}
```

I´m using `dbDelta()`.
When I tried to intall my plugin on an other Wordpress, on activation, I got this error :

> This extension generated 45515 unexpected output characters when activated. If you notice "headers already sent" messages, problems with your syndication feeds, or other concerns, try disabling or removing this extension.

I activated the debug mode to get more information and I saw this error in `debug.log` :

> WordPress Database Error Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes pour la requête CREATE TABLE foo

Unfortunately, I cannot catch this error with `dbDelta()`.

So what is the best alternative to create tables in wordpress but catch error in case of failure ?

Comment: have you see this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141971/why-does-dbdelta-not-catch-mysqlerrors/141984) ?

Comment: @Dhruv, yes I saw this link but the answers are not complete or with some mistakes.